# Generated column in a view counting related rows

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, view

I have 2 related models, model_A and model_B. There's a 1:n relationship among them, one row in model_A can have several related rows in model_B.

model_A is a view, created with `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_name AS (...`
model_B is an ordinary table.

I'd like one of the columns of model_A to contain the number of related records in model_B. How do I achieve that?

Definition of model_A:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW prestazioni_preventivate AS (
select 
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY res_valutazione.id, prestazione_preventivata) as id,
generate_series(1,res_prestazione.occorrenze_totali) as prestazione_preventivata,
res_valutazione.id AS valutazione_id,
res_valutazione.stringa_valutazione, 
res_valutazione.studio_id, 
res_valutazione.overhead, 
res_valutazione.accepted_overhead,
res_braccio.id AS braccio_id,
res_braccio.seleziona_braccio,
res_braccio.n_pazienti,
res_prestazione.id as prestazione_id,
tipo_prestazione.name AS prestazione,
tipo_prestazione.id AS tipo_prestazione_id,
res_prestazione.is_conditional,
res_week.id AS week,
res_prestazione.quantita,
res_prestazione.occorrenze_totali
from 
res_valutazione 
LEFT OUTER JOIN res_braccio ON res_braccio.valutazione_id = res_valutazione.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN res_prestazione ON res_prestazione.braccio_id = res_braccio.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tipo_prestazione ON res_prestazione.tipo_prestazione_ids = tipo_prestazione.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN res_week ON res_valutazione.id = res_week.valutazione_id AND res_braccio.id = res_week.braccio_id AND res_prestazione.id = res_week.prestazione_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN generate_series(1,res_prestazione.occorrenze_totali) as prestazione_preventivata on true
WHERE res_valutazione.studio_id is not  null
AND
res_valutazione.accepted_overhead is TRUE
ORDER BY res_valutazione.studio_id, res_braccio.seleziona_braccio         )
```

Definition of model_B:

```
> describe eroga_prestazione;
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Column                      | Type                        | Modifiers                                                       |
|-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| id                          | integer                     |  not null default nextval('eroga_prestazione_id_seq'::regclass) |
| data                        | timestamp without time zone |                                                                 |
| paziente_id                 | integer                     |                                                                 |
| studio_id                   | integer                     |                                                                 |
| prestazione_ids             | integer                     |                                                                 |
| costo_tariffario            | double precision            |                                                                 |
| onorario                    | double precision            |                                                                 |
| company_id                  | integer                     |                                                                 |
| currency_id                 | integer                     |  not null                                                       |
| create_uid                  | integer                     |                                                                 |
| create_date                 | timestamp without time zone |                                                                 |
| write_uid                   | integer                     |                                                                 |
| write_date                  | timestamp without time zone |                                                                 |
| supporto_sanitario_diretto  | double precision            |                                                                 |
| medico_id                   | integer                     |                                                                 |
| infermiere_id               | integer                     |                                                                 |
| tecnico_id                  | integer                     |                                                                 |
| percentuale_infermiere      | integer                     |                                                                 |
| quota_infermiere            | double precision            |                                                                 |
| percentuale_tecnico         | integer                     |                                                                 |
| quota_tecnico               | double precision            |                                                                 |
| prestazione_preventivata_id | integer                     |                                                                 |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
Indexes:
    "eroga_prestazione_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "eroga_prestazione_company_id_index" btree (company_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "eroga_prestazione_company_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES res_company(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    "eroga_prestazione_create_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (create_uid) REFERENCES res_users(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    "eroga_prestazione_currency_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (currency_id) REFERENCES res_currency(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "eroga_prestazione_infermiere_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (infermiere_id) REFERENCES sc_personale(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    "eroga_prestazione_medico_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (medico_id) REFERENCES sc_personale(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    "eroga_prestazione_paziente_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (paziente_id) REFERENCES res_partner(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    "eroga_prestazione_prestazione_ids_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (prestazione_ids) REFERENCES tipo_prestazione(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    "eroga_prestazione_studio_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (studio_id) REFERENCES res_studio(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    "eroga_prestazione_tecnico_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (tecnico_id) REFERENCES sc_personale(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    "eroga_prestazione_write_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (write_uid) REFERENCES res_users(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
Referenced by:
    TABLE "prestazione_personale_rel" CONSTRAINT "prestazione_personale_rel_eroga_prestazione_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (eroga_prestazione_id) REFERENCES eroga_prestazione(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

In model_B (`eroga_prestazione`), the reference to model_A (`prestazioni_preventivate`) is `prestazione_preventivata_id`

Much of this is created through the Odoo ORM, I don't know why `prestazione_preventivata_id` is not a foreign key in model_B (`eroga_prestazione`).

Comment: maybe model_A could be a materialized view and there could be a bunch of triggers to update it everytime that's needed ?

Comment: You will minimally need to provide the View definition for `model_A` and show which fields relate it to `model_B`, in order for anyone to be able to answer you.

Comment: @J.D.thank you, I edited the question and added some context

Comment: In the view, `prestazione_preventivata` is generated (thus multiplying rows), but not included in the output. Doesn't seem to make sense. Also `prestazioni_preventivate.id` is generated with `row_number()` without `ORDER BY`, so it's an arbitrary number. Also doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: As for prestazione_preventivata not being included in the output, I'm not sure what that means. Does it mean you want a describe on it too ? @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: I mean that `generate_series()` returns a set with a single column named `prestazione_preventivata`, but that's not included in the `SELECT` list. The query doesn't seem to make sense. Also, FK constraints are only possible between tables. There seem to be multiple misunderstandings.

Comment: I added the ` ` ` generate_series` ` `  in the select and I added an ordering in the ` ` ` row_number` ` `  @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: The question is still impossible to answer. The source of your virtual (impossible) FK constraint is `eroga_prestazione.prestazione_preventivata_id`, but the target column is undefined. Also, you added `generate_series()` twice now, which surely can't be what you want.